# Trying to restart my Twitch API from scratch. Not sure how to get my response

Tags: json, api, twitch

I'm in the process of redesigning my website, and with this I wanted to update/improve the various scripts involved. One such script is a call to the Twitch API for a set group of streamers, then displaying who's online and, if any are, displaying the first live stream and allow the user to switch between them.

My original script, which works great, was originally constructed by somebody here on StackOverflow. The problem is that instead of guiding me to a usable answer, they just rewrote my code to work in a way that I have a hard time following. I honestly have no idea how the loop they made works. It works, and I use it now, but that's my mistake. I want to start fresh and get a return for each user in an array, then construct things out based on the results of their live status. I don't understand how it is currently being done with this code, and I can't seem to figure out the point where it is saving the return, so I can't properly log it to the console to look at it and use it proper.

Long story short, can anybody help me with a simple return in a loop for each user so I can log it to the console and look at it and use it DIRECTLY instead of saving pieces to a million variables? Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var casters = ["marcusraven86","whit3rabbit87","dragonbornmonocle","m3ta1head","jimmyjojo7","redshoes","sergeantatams","stevechopz"];

var castersLive = [];

var reqs = $.map(casters, function (userName, i) {

    return $.getJSON('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/' + userName + '.json?callback=?');

})

$.when.apply($, reqs).done(function () {

    $.each(arguments, function (i, array) {

        var data = array[0];

        var userName = casters[i];

        console.log(data);

        if (data.stream === null) {

            $('<div class="streampost"></div>').append(

                '<a id="offline' + userName + '" class = "offline" href="http://www.twitch.tv/' + userName + '/profile" title="' + userName + '" target="_blank"></a>').appendTo('#statusblock');

        } 

        else {

            castersLive.push(casters[i]);

            $('<div class="streampost"></div>').append(

                '<a id="online' + userName + '" class = "online" href="http://player.twitch.tv/?channel=' + userName + '"  title="' + userName + '" target="stream"></a>').appendTo('#statusblock');

        }

    });

    console.log(castersLive);

    if (castersLive.length > 0) {

        $('<div class="streamplayer embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"></div>').append('<iframe src="http://player.twitch.tv/?channel=' + castersLive[0] +'" name="stream"></iframe><iframe src="http://www.twitch.tv/' + castersLive[0] + '/chat?popout=" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" height="478" width="350" id="chatFrame" name="chatFrame"></iframe>').appendTo('#streamblock');

    }

    else {}


    $('.online').click(function() {

    var streamName = $(this).attr('title');

    $('#chatFrame').attr('src', 'http://www.twitch.tv/' + streamName + '/chat?popout=');

});
});
});
```

And here is where I'm trying to restart, but I can't seem to get the call to the API correct. I'm still a bit new to all this, and I also use the Tumblr and YouTube APIs. Each is different, and it throws me off a little.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var casters = ["marcusraven86","whit3rabbit87","dragonbornmonocle","m3ta1head","jimmyjojo7","redshoes","sergeantatams","stevechopz"];

var castersLive = [];

for (i=0; i <= casters.length; i++) {
    $.get('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/' + casters[i] + '.json?callback=?'), function ( data ) {
    console.log(data);
    };
};
```